# Any suggestion for a reliable video format for industrial applications?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing, mpeg-4, mkv

I am currently using videos encoded in MPEG4 (h264). This makes the content of the frames rely on the content of other frames.

In my case this is undesirable as I often need to quickly split video files without re-compressing or altering the content and seek many times trough the video.

The video format that I need needs to be reliable and the frames need to be independent from each other.

Any idea on which video format might be best for these requirements?

Maybe there is a sub-type of MPEG4 encoding that allows to reach this result?

Answer (score 1):

H.264 with the intra flag will encode to a video stream where each frame can be independently decoded.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -c:v libx264 -g 1 -c:a copy out.mp4
```

`-g 1` sets GOP size to 1 frame, hence each frame is intra-coded. Of course, the video bitrate will increase - in some cases, quite a bit - relative to omitting this flag.

Comment: Assuming the requirement of 'reliable' means surviving a level or corruption,  I would recommend agains mp4. Corruption of the `moov` could make the file very difficult to parse later. If audio is not needed, annex B would work well, otherwise something like ts would be good

Comment: Agreed. OP hasn't been specific on what reliable mean here.